# How do I configure a new docker-compose.yml file in an existing WordPress git repository?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have a WordPress git repository that I'd like to add a docker-compose.yml.

```
/wp-admin
/wp-content
/wp-includes
README.md
composer.json
composer.lock
index.php
license.txt
readme.html
wp-activate.php
wp-blog-header.php
wp-comments-post.php
wp-config.php
wp-cron.php
wp-links-opml.php
wp-load.php
wp-login.php
wp-mail.php
wp-settings.php
wp-signup.php
wp-trackback.php
xmlrpc.php
```

I'm familiar with using a docker-compose.yml file to run WordPress locally.  I'm currently using the sample from https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/:

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}
```

How can I add a docker-compose.yml file to my existing repository and have the contents of the repository's /wp-content directory be mapped to the /wp-content directory running in the WordPress container?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be committing core wordpress files to your repo.

Every time you `docker-compose up -d` your project, docker uses the current/latest image from your docker desktop app.

```yml
    image: wordpress:latest
```

So it is pointless mapping directly to `wordpress_data:/var/www/html` and is dangerous adding files to this when running wordpress updates.

Same goes for your `db_data:/var/lib/mysql` as this will be reset everytime you docker compose up and down. Database will not be persistent this way which means your db will reset every time you docker down.

The best way to fix your issue, is to pull your repo locally, delete all core wordpress files, and move the `wp-content` sub folders to the root of your repo like this...

[image]

1. Include your `docker-compose.yml` here.
2. Add a `.gitignore` file here too containing this to exclude the heavy stuff from your repo...

```txt
/db
/plugins
/uploads
```

3. Add an `uploads.ini` file containing this to allow local uploads...

```ini
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_execution_time = 600
```

4. Finally add an empty `db` folder. (this is optional as our `docker-compose.yml` will create one if it doesn't exist)

Now for your `docker-compose.yml` to use everything re-arranged above correctly...

```yml
version: '3.9'

networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:

  # here is our mysql database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is our wordpress server
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data mapping
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wordpress
    environment:

      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1

      # docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb

      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /* development parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');

        /* configure mail server */
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH', false);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE', '');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST', 'mailhog');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT', '1025');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM', 'no-reply@yoursitedomain.com');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME', 'Your Site Title');

        if(!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          /* force our home url */
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }


  # here is our mail hog server
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

For [mailhog](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog/) to work and receive outgoing mail from your local wordpress environment you will need to add this to your `functions.php`...

```
// add the action
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'action_wp_mail_failed', 10, 1);

// configure PHPMailer to send through SMTP
add_action('phpmailer_init', function ($phpmailer) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // host details
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $phpmailer->Host = WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->Port = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT;
    // from details
    $phpmailer->From = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME;
    // login details
    $phpmailer->Username = WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $phpmailer->Password = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD;

});
```

Now these urls below will work...

- [http://localhost](http://locolhost) - your site
- http://localhost/admin - your site wp admin (once site is setup)
- http://localhost:8025 - mailhog for viewing outgoing mail from your local wordpress site

So every time you `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` on this project, your environment will boot up exactly where you left off.

Now commit your repo, which now excludes wordpress core files allowing you to safely manage wordpress updates via the docker desktop app.

`db`, `plugin` and `uploads` will be persistent data locally but this will not be committed to your repo because we excluded them using the `.gitignore` file. So make sure these are backed up some how incase your machine dies. Bad practice to commit these to repositories as they are very large in file size.